# Custom UINavigation Bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I've came across a few tutorials on how to customize the navigation bar on the iPhone. Apparently some of the methods used are not approved by Apple, anybody has an app approved that was using a custom navigation bar and if so how did you do it? Thank you.

Comment: How do you want to customize the navigation bar?

Comment: Hello, I want to add an image.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 5, you can easily set an image into your NavigationBar by calling:

```
[navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Before iOS 5, there is no public API to do so. You have to do it by yourself, and all of those ways are going to be in trouble in iOS 5 because the NavigationBar has changed a lot in the new iOS.

*P.S. Maybe I should not talk about iOS 5 things here because it is not released yet and still under Apple's NDA...*

Comment: ok but do you know a way i could implement it for now and when IOS 5 gets released we will update it?

Comment: By implementing this on my app delegate it works fine but is Apple gonna approve it?

Comment: This is iOS 5 feature, but you can still use this code for iOS 4 by check `[navigationBar respondsToSelect:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)]` before you use it. And the code will be automatically enabled in iOS 5 without any code modify needed.

Comment: It's good to know it works. If you think this answer is helpful, select it as correct answer would very appreciate.

Comment: Sure, quick question i'm trying to add a static image on top of a UITableView(not inside the cell) do you know how could i do that, just a static image on the view.

Comment: Maybe you can make a UIImageView with your static image, and set it as UITableView's `tableHeaderView`

Comment: `tableView.tableHeaderView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"staticImage.png"]] autorelease];` for example.